# Force application to use specific stereo channel only

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have two applications that use both stereo channels but don't allow to balance them into one channel only.

Is there any way to capture and force audio from those apps so one would go to left channel and second would go to right?

I'm on windows 10 pc.

Comment: Use a virtual soundcard for each that allows balancing and output the sound through your normal card. Virtual Audio Cable, Voicemeeter etc. could be helpful.

Comment: @Seth , Thanks i tried to use Virtual Audio Cable but it was out-of-sync .  It seems that computing time was long enough to create audio some ~1s late compared to video in browser.

Comment: If that causes a one second delay, you're running on quite slow hardware?

Comment: @Seth, TY for comment. I run on Intel i7 16gb laptop. Rather fast machine. So i guess either the software has problem or i couldn't setup it correctly.